# React Router v6 Display all components (routes) on single page SPA (scrollable)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have been trying to use `react-router` and I am unable to get all of my pages to render and display on one page (*not having to click on `<Link>`'s to see each page*).

All of my site pages will display when the `<Route>` path is clicked on in the `NavBar.jsx` but will only show that specific component.

I've read through a lot of different articles and have looked at [React Router v6 Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq) for help and have tried using their [Example](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/multi-app?file=home/main.jsx) but I am still unable to get all of my Pages to display onload (SPA) without the user having to click on links to get to each page.

****My Code Snippets:****

**`App.jsx`**

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
      <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/about' component={About} />
  </Routes>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

`NavBar.jsx`

```
<Nav>
  <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
  <Link to="/about">About</Link>
</Nav>
```

***(localhost:3000/ --> Displays Home page)
(localhost:3000/about --> Displays About page)
etc.***

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if you are using this `react-router-6` then you need this syntax:

```
 <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path='/home' element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path='/about' element={<About />}/>
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

You can check inside `package.json` file inside your project folder which version of router are you using.

Comment: My ```package.json``` has- ``` "react-router": "^6.0.1", "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",```                                                                            
and when I use ```<Routes>``` under BrowserRouter I get this error- ```Attempted import error: 'Routes' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.```

Comment: Okay, then replace `Routes` with `Switch` and import `Switch` inside file. Also, are you using ts or js inside project?

Comment: I am using jsx. I replaced ```<Routes>``` with ```<Switch>``` and now none of the pages are showing.

Comment: Can you try to do it like on this example? It's using `react-router-dom 5.3.0`
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/basic . If you are using `Switch` that means that you are using v5 `react-router-dom` which means that you need to use `component` instead of `element`

Comment: I used the format from the example and the pages are showing again but still, only one page shows at a time when ```<Link>``` is clicked.

Comment: If you want to see every component on every page, just create component page and import all this three components inside that page component and add pass that page as component inside Route :)

Comment: I created a separate Container with the ```<Route>```'s and now all pages are showing on one page . Thanks @VeselinKontić